# React router change state without using Link

Tags: react-router

So I obviously know how to do this:

```
<Link to="/picture/123" state={{ fromDashboard: true }} />
```

And that you can change states by also passing it in.

I know that if you don't want to use link, i.e. you want to programmatically navigate, then you'd have to use this:

```
browserHistory.push('/url');
```

But what is the alternative, to changing the router state?

So this is what I currently know:

- Using 'Link' to go to new route (KNOWN)
- Using 'Link' to pass in state (KNOWN)
- Alternative function to go to new route (KNOWN)
- Alternative function to pass in router state (???)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<Link>` props that you used above are actually dated. When it isn't just the `pathname` that you want to use for navigation, the `to` prop should be an object, which is referred to as a "location descriptor".

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/picture/123', state: { fromDashboard: true } }} />
```

Similarly, you can push a location descriptor to the history.

```
browserHistory.push({
  pathname: '/picture/123',
  state: { fromDashboard: true }
});
```

Comment: It works, I don't know why this example wasn't on the docs. Anyway, how would you incorporate variables in the pathname? i.e. the old example would be something like `comment/${this.props.num}`.

Comment: Same way, build the string with template literals { pathname: `comment/${this.props.num}` }.

Comment: The docs may not include the location descriptor in a `browserHistory` example, but they are included in the `withRouter` https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/docs/API.md#pushpathorloc and `Link` https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/docs/API.md#to documentation.

Comment: Oddly enough I did look at that RouterContext #push method, but I tried something like RouterContext.context.router, something complicated but nothing worked. And building building pathname with those template literals doesn't work for me. I just did someting like '/'+this.props.num+'/comment' and it worked